# Wireless PCI Card Linksys WMP54G V2 doesn't work in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: wireless, pci

after spending my time in a lot of website without result, I hope someone could help me.

I have a PCI Card Linksys (not recent...) model **WMP54G V2**, which doesn't work in **ubuntu 12.04**.

Ubuntu automatically find this driver:  **Driver Broadcom STA wireless**, but during the installation, the procedure seem freeze it self; (the installation bar still run, but nothing happens)

So I reboot the PC, and looking into *"additional driver menu"* and driver is installed:  well!

Then I try to add a wireless connection from *"network menu"* but i can't see  wireless card.

I've tryed to install diver **b-43XX** from software center but without result.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: You wireless card is the same as my Dads. The WMP54G V2. It is covered in the question marked as duplicate in http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-sta-wireless-card-bcm43xx

Answer (score 0):

If you are having real trouble with the linux drivers with broadcom which is no surprise. I can suggest using ndiswrapper and use the windows driver. This creates a wrapper around the windows driver and allows you to use it for wireless on your Linux machine.

You can install it from the repos with apt-get install ndiswrapper ndiswrapper-utils. Its also has a GUI based tool from Ubuntu in GTK+ framework called ndiswrapper-gtk. Just add the windows driver to that and see how its goes. The GUI is very self explanatory.

But I have also posted the link to the ndiswrapper wiki for any other information.

[LINKY HERE](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ndiswrapper/index.php?title=Main_Page)

Comment: I'm not sure how you can propose ndiswrapper without knowing the device ID from lspci. A great many Broadcom devices work quite well with the native Linux driver and without ndiswrapper.